# Page does not display correctly (blank page) in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm new to development, and I can't wrap my head around why this will not display correctly in Firefox. I simply have a centered div with a background, and a background in the body. Nothing will display in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Because your div/body has no content and does not have a fixed height/width.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. :) Thanks folks! I had my header in an include file in the /include folder. So I was pointing to my css using relative path ..\style.css. Apparently this works in IE and Chrome but not Firefox. /style.css made it work!